# Setting and using custom properties of HTML objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, properties, custom-properties

I am trying to make a simple battleships game where a 10x10 table is used as the playing field. I want to be able to change the boat length and number of boats easily, which is why I am (attempting) to store information against the HTML object (table cell). The table has unique ids for each cell, written as cell_3_8.

My question is on how I can use a custom property, in this case, hasBoat in order to store and change information about the cells. I have set every cell to have the property hasBoat to 0 at the beginning, and am setting the value to 1 when I want a boat to be placed there. At the moment, nothing is happening to the table when I try to place boats, and when checking in the Chrome console, it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'hasBoat' of null".

If you could explain what the problem is here, and even better, how to fix it, that would be great. Here is the code:

```
var boatCell
var boatNum;
var boatLen
var boatPos;

function getCoordinate() {

    for (boatNum = 1; boatNum < 4; boatNum++) {
        for (boatLen = 1; boatLen < 4; boatLen++) {
            var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
            var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
            x = x++;
            boatPos = "cell_" + "_" + x + "_" + y;
            boatCell = document.getElementById(boatPos);
            boatCell.hasBoat = 1;
        }
            if (boatCell.hasBoat == 1) {
                boatCell.style.backgroundColor = "brown";
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: boatCell.hasBoat = 1; is correct. What you are doing wrong is your selector document.getElementById(boatPos); return null. If you put some HTML code it would help.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is because you dont have an element with id = "cell_" + "" + x + "" + y; and boatCell = document.getElementById(boatPos); is set the value of your variable boatCell to null, see the example

```js
var exist = document.getElementById("cell_1_4");
console.log(exist);

var notExist = document.getElementById("cell_1_3");
console.log(notExist);
```

```html
<div id="cell_1_4"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is not about setting the `hasBoat` attribute. Instead, it is that `boatCell` is `null`. I believe you meant to have the `if` inside the inner `for`, like so:

```
for (boatNum = 1; boatNum < 4; boatNum++) {
    for (boatLen = 1; boatLen < 4; boatLen++) {
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
        x = x++;
        boatPos = "cell_" + "_" + x + "_" + y;
        boatCell = document.getElementById(boatPos);
        boatCell.hasBoat = 1;

        if (boatCell.hasBoat == 1) {
            boatCell.style.backgroundColor = "brown";
        }
    }
}
```